# Dimensionar altura do header dinamicamente

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Então, eu tenho a seguinte estrutura **HTML**

```
<div>
    <header>Esse é o cabeçalho</header>
    <article>Esse é o artigo que vem sobre do cabeçalho</article>
</div>
```

Tenho umas 10 `div's` dessa uma abaixo da outra.

**O problema**: Tem `header` que tem um texto muto grande tipo umas 10 palavras e outros menores. Então, quando vou reduzir a tela para **mobile** o **header** que antes ocupava **1 linha** agora passa a ocupar **2 linhas**.

E isso, atrapalha o uso do `line-height` de apenas 1 linha.

Existe algum recurso onde eu consigo calcular em **tempo de execução** e aplicar para cada `header` o `line-header` correspondente?

Atualmente estou fazendo algo como:

```
div > header {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
}
```

Mas isso só funciona para uma linha.

Algum recurso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao avaliar esse estrutura percebe-se claramente que vc tentou centralizar verticalmente o texto dentro da div usando um `line-height: 50px;` com o mesmo valor do `height: 50px;`. Não é que isso seja totalmente errado, mas é gambiarra, não se deve usar `line-height` para fazer alinhamento de texto... `line-height`  é para controlar o distanciamento entre uma linha é outra, não para centralizar nada, 90% das vezes que vejo essa propriedade sendo usada é de maneira equivocada, a utilidade dela é apenas para formatação tipográfica do texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> The `line-height` CSS property sets the height of a line box. **It's commonly used to set the distance between lines of text**.

Recomendo que entre nesse link para ver a propriedade funcionando em um exemplo prático e ver a documentação e aplicação https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Uma alternativa simples é colocar display: flex na `div > header`  e alinhar o texto com `align-itens: center`. Assim mesmo que o texto quebre linha ele se manterá no centro do `header`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
header,
article {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div > header {
   height: 50px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>Esse é o cabeçalho</header>
  <article>Esse é o artigo que vem sobre do cabeçalho</article>
</div>
<div>
  <header>Esse é o cabeçalho Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. autem!</header>
  <article>Esse é o artigo que vem sobre do cabeçalho</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado hugo, deu certo!

Comment: @CarlosRocha sem problemas meu caro! Sempre tenha em mente que line-height é para controlar o espaço entre uma linha e outra de um <p> por exemplo. Esse tipo de uso para alinhar não é aconselhável...